# NodeJS Retriivng Record from DB 1 by 1 vs All

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have 2 Microservices

- 1 Auth Service : Store all the users Data
- 2 Club Service : Store userId Ref ( of a Auth Service User ) along with Service Specific Data

in the Club service i want to get all the users data but i only want the users subscribed to my Club Service (Not all users in Auth Service)
so i have 2 options
 2 functions in Club Service (Shared from Auth Service using RPC (MicroService))

1 - getUserById

2 - getAllUsers

should i make a for loop and supply the userId to getUserById Function to get all data related to Club Service only

or should i getAllUsers data from auth. Store them in an array and then loop through this array with the UserId to get the users data specific to my Club Service ?

Which is more Performant

It's all about which is more performant querying the data from DB one by one using getUserById method

or

getting all the Data from DB once. send them to Club Service. and on Club Service i loop through all the data to match the userId i have on Club Service and filter them?

Comment: It varies, but as a rule of thumb it's usually preferable to reduce communication, as it's prone to errors. Fetch as much as you can in as little amount of calls as possible

Comment: so i should fetch all users ? let say i have 200 users in auth. and i need only 50 of them because only 50 exsist in Club Service. should i fetch all 200 at once and then filter the 50 one that i need from them? or fetch the 50 one by one ?

Comment: If you can fetch 50 one by one, why not query only 50 at once @mohamedadel?

Comment: i will have to make a new function in auth. that takes array of userId. and return all the data of the users in the userId array. Is it worth it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In microservice, this is one of the common tasks you will face. So, instead of doing a call to the user in the loop you just make use of aggregate match.

In user service, you just make a route as `/read-many`, here in the controller or repository you can write aggregate with a match query.

```
eg `aggregate[{$match: match}] // here match will be variable`
```

So, from Club first, make all collect all the value into an array.eg 
`const users = ["id1", "id2"]` 
Now you just need to call to user service with userId variable this will return you all the Club subscribed result.
I hope it may help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Communication between servers (i.e. micro services) is always more prone to errors than using "local" data.

Therefore (obviously within limits of security, privacy, bandwidth limits etc.) I'd recommend to make your calls in batches:

1. Fetching as many users as possible in a single call.
2. Authenticating as many users as possible at the same time.

This will guarantee less calls between your micro services, resulting in a more readable code, a more reliable and easily-read error handling and usually a slightly better performing code.